How to make `TAM::tam` work when fixing the item difficulties, and when there are columns with single values in R?
library(TAM)
# Data with 3 items and 1 candidate
data <- t(c(item1 = 1, item2 = 0, item3 = 1))
# Define a fixed difficulty matrix
difficulty_matrix <- cbind(1:3, c(1.5, 2.0, 1.0))
# Fit the TAM model with fixed difficulty
tam(data, xsi.fixed = difficulty_matrix, verbose = F)

I get a an error message
Items with maximum score of 0: item2
Error in dimnames(A.draft) <- `*vtmp*` : 
  length of 'dimnames' [3] not equal to array extent

I could add one fictitious row so that there wouldn't be the error but I want to know if there is one parameter in the tam function to avoid this error.
For info, I just want to get the person's ability.
